# iOS - background fetch and threads

Tags: ios, background-process

I have app, that uses background fetch and update location during it. It works fine with this code:

```
-(void)backgroundDidUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{    
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier locationUpdateTaskID = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
    ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{            
            if (locationUpdateTaskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {

                if (_backgroundFetchCompletionHandler != nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"BG location finished 1");
                    _backgroundFetchCompletionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                    _backgroundFetchCompletionHandler = nil;
                }

                [app endBackgroundTask:locationUpdateTaskID];
                locationUpdateTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    ^{                        
        if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myLocationManager:didUpdateLocations:)])
        {
            [_delegate myLocationManager:self didUpdateLocations:locations];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{            
            if (locationUpdateTaskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                if (_backgroundFetchCompletionHandler != nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"BG location finished 2");
                    _backgroundFetchCompletionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                    _backgroundFetchCompletionHandler = nil;
                }

                [app endBackgroundTask:locationUpdateTaskID];
                locationUpdateTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });

}
```

But there is a problem with this:

```
[_delegate myLocationManager:self didUpdateLocations:locations];
```

if I use some simple call, it fine. But if `_delegate` method runs some another background operation, like download data from internet, I have a problem. Download is started asynchronously, so my background fetch is "closed" with `backgroundFetchCompletionHandler` before data are delivered. Data are than delivered outside of this scope and I am afraid, it can cause some problems. How to solve this problem correctly?

**Edit:**
I can not modify `_delegate` code, so pass handler as variable is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delegate is set and responds then pass it the completion handler so that it can do its work and call the completion handler when it's done. If the delegate isn't set or doesn't respond then call the completion handler directly.

Comment: Problem is I can not modify _delegate code, so pass handler there is not possible.

Comment: Why can't you modify it? If it can't tell you when it's done then you don't really have options...

Comment: I can not modify _delegate directly, but _delegate cals selector after data are downloaded and from there I manage data and fill them to CoreData. But LocationManager and Selector dont see each other. So only solution, that comes to my mind is use "static shared" variable and pass handler via it. (or maybe there is some more clever ios style solution)

Comment: I'd look at implementing a wrapper around the delegate (a facade) such that the delegate can provide a nice interface for your usage, implemented internally using the delegate callback selector.